# How many Custom Events Can I Track with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Non-premium analytics allows 5 Custom Variables. Does that mean I can only track 5 Custom Events or is that a totally separate thing?

Pretty straight forward question, but I haven't had much luck googling for an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Variables and custom events are not related - even on the technical side they are quite different as a custom variable is transmitted as a part of an interaction hit while an event is an interaction hit within its own right.

So you can define up to five different custom variables which can hold arbitrary values and attach them to each interaction hit (meaning that while you have only five slots the values can of course be different for each hit).

As far as events are concerned, within the data limits (which is 10 mio interaction hits per account per month for the free version)  you can have as many as you like - technically they are not very different from pageviews (in fact with Universal Analytics you have a single send method for all interactions and specify the interaction type as a parameter).

Comment: Thanks Eike. Very helpful reply!